# How can I access post params on rails 4 ussing device?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a custom controller for the registration process with device and rails 4. 
I am tracing params hash

```
logger.info "Test:" << params.to_yaml 

utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: VFWT....
user: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
user_name: test
first_name: test
last_name: test
display_name: test
email: test@gmail.com
password: testpassword
password_confirmation: testpassword
commit: Sign up
action: create
controller: registrations
```

But when I am trying to access the hash on the controller

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
logger.info "Test:" << params[:email]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Something is nil, it can be either the `params` object or `params[:email]`

Comment: haha something is nil indeed !

Comment: @MrYoshiji its `params[:email] ` that is nil ;)